# Webview setDownloadListener files not downloading with same name

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, download, android-download-manager

I'm Using Webview setDownloadListener for downloading files, All things are working fine but when I downloaded the files its name gets changes like `abc.pdf` to `hc7sgcgdscbsjajncagv.pdf` How to solve this problem. I want exact same name + suffix `my_project_name` Please help me to do that. Thanks In Advance

**My Code**

```
        webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie",cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent",userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Downloading File...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMlIS.jpg)

Comment: `URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType)` Please tell what this function returns. And please tell why you call it three times.

Comment: @blackapps Sorry, I did 80% of the code and copied last some lines from here. So I'm not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

FYI, from official docs

> guessFileName guesses canonical filename that a download would have, using the URL and contentDisposition. File extension, if not defined, is added based on the mimetype

There is no automatic way to set the name for your downloaded file. You need set the name manually for your file like below.

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "abc" + "your_suffix" + ".pdf");
```